# LibGDX proguard

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, proguard, obfuscation

I have been trying to shrink the size of my libGDX game .jar. I have been trying to get proguard to work. Proguard keeps complaining about missing classes, or the output .jar won't run.

I have tried all the existing configuration files I found for libGDX.

Does anyone have experience with setting up proguard?

Comment: It is a little too open ended of a question, as given, and there are no examples and output from Proguard.  Give us an MCVE and we will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following configuration for libGDX:

```
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.**
-dontnote com.badlogic.gdx.**

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Cubemap* { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL* { *; }

# for Android backend
-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {
    <init>(com.badlogic.gdx.Application, android.content.Context, java.lang.Object, com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration);
}

# for box2d plugin
-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World {
    boolean contactFilter(long, long);
    void    beginContact(long);
    void    endContact(long);
    void    preSolve(long, long);
    void    postSolve(long, long);
    boolean reportFixture(long);
    float   reportRayFixture(long, float, float, float, float, float);
}
```

Comment: Not working, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915959/proguard-simexception

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ProGuard-DexGuard-and-libGDX

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-verbose

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.utils.Box2DBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget*

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {
   <init>(com.badlogic.gdx.Application, android.content.Context, java.lang.Object, com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration);
}

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World {
   boolean contactFilter(long, long);
   void    beginContact(long);
   void    endContact(long);
   void    preSolve(long, long);
   void    postSolve(long, long);
   boolean reportFixture(long);
   float   reportRayFixture(long, float, float, float, float, float);
}
```