# ProGuard SimException

Tags: java, android, libgdx, proguard

I'm trying to get ProGuard to work, after roughly 4 hours of randomly trying options to try and get this amazing software to work.

My project is using LibGDX and KryoNet. This is my current ProGuard configuration:

```
-verbose
-dontobfuscate

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget*
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreetypeBuild

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {
   <init>(com.badlogic.gdx.Application, android.content.Context, java.lang.Object, com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration);
}

# Kryo
-dontwarn sun.reflect.**
-dontwarn java.beans.**
-dontwarn sun.nio.ch.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.**

-keep class com.esotericsoftware.kryo.** {*;}
-keep class com.esotericsoftware.** {*;}

-keep class java.beans.** { *; }
-keep class sun.reflect.** { *; }
-keep class sun.nio.ch.** { *; }
```

This does not compile. It throws multiple of the following errors: `Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type float using a local variable of type int. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.`

I found some information about this error: [Compile with Proguard gives SimException: "local variable type mismatch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701126/compile-with-proguard-gives-exception-local-variable-type-mismatch).

The solution given was to edit some main-rules.xml file from ANT, but I'm using Gradle. A comment was posted with a fix for Gradle : to add `project.tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex) { additionalParameters=['--no-locals'] }`. But apparently the Dex class is removed, so this no longer works.

I read this is a bug in ProGuard, and that obfuscating should fix it. But when I remove the `-dontobfuscate` line, my app does not start anymore: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.a.a.c.a.k.g() (tried Java_com_a_a_c_a_k_g and Java_com_a_a_c_a_k_g__)`.

Does anyone know how to work around these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be related to a specific optimization of ProGuard.
You can disable it like that:

```
-optimizations !code/allocation/variable
```

Furthermore you can also remove the LocalVariableTable and LocalVariableTypeTable attributes which do not seem to be updated properly (and are not needed in an application anymore).  For this you would need to enable obfuscation though and then use something like:

```
-keepattributes !LocalVariable*,**
```

This rule would keep all attributes but the LocalVariable related ones.

The obfuscation problem with libGDX might be solved by this rule:

```
# Keep names - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

Comment: When using your additions, the compilation is successful but the app crashes after a while: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label.getStyle()' on a null object reference

Comment: This is most likely caused by obfuscation (or am I completely wrong?)